# Registry Key on Windows 10 for Enrolled User (InTune / Autopilot)

Tags: windows, intune, user-enrollment

Ultimately, I am trying to see if there is a registry key on the local Windows box to tell me who enrolled an Intune Managed Device.

I have looked in many different locations, and haven't been able to identify a key that stores this information